# Maven copy dependencies with full jar name

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I want to copy maven dependencies to ${project.build.directory}/lib.

I am using below plugin:

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

But this is copying jars only artifact name. Ex:

```
antlr-2.7.7.jar, aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.134.jar
```

Is there a way I can have groupId as well in name. Ex:

```
antlr.antlr-2.7.7.jar, com.amazonaws.aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.134.jar
```

Basically I need some property like:

```
<DependencyName>${dep.groupId}.${dep.artifactId}-${dep.version}<DependencyName>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `<prependGroupId>` to `true` (in the `<configuration>`).